# How many days we should wait to go to doctor after pregnancy confirmation

Tags: obstetrics, gynecology

If a female 35 years old confirms pregnancy herself with urine test at home using the pregnancy test card on her 36th day of cycle. She can view two clear pink lines in that card. she confirmed it twice with her early morning first urine.

Now, can she go to doctor immediately on the 36 days and do ultrasound or should she wait 5/10 more days?